# Best hardware for Android and Google TV development

Tags: android

Is anyone keeping track of the best hardware software development environment for Android/Eclipse development ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think there is any specific hardware that would make developing for android **THAT** much better. I would suggest a computer though that is running windows 7 and has a minimum of 6gbs of RAM

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and 6GB+ of RAM for development.

Have an SSD on your desktop for holding the emulator images. Without an SSD emulator startup time is crazy...